# XCode Interface Builder Auto Layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

i have `UILabel` (red colored) on top and `UIScrollView` (blue colored) at the bottom of it. I have set all constraints for UILabel and at the same time I have set `UIScrollView` Top Space To: UILabel = 10.

Now when my app is loaded everything looks good. But, i am dynamically changing height of my `UILabel` depending on its text and logically when height of `UILabel` increases `UIScrollView` should automatically go down to keep constraint. But this does not happen. ScrollView stays as it is and overlaps with increased UILabel.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do not use constraint for `height` for the red label, it should work.

Comment: if you change the height dynamically, you have to that via manipulating the constraint. if yuo do this, everything should work fine

Comment: if you set the top constraint of scroll view relatively to the label then every thing will works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do.
With all of your current settings,

- Don't use height constraint for label,
- set number of line to 0 to label

You don't need to add any calculation of height of label, it will adjust it's height according to text

**PS:** if you want to have some height constraint to set minimum height of label, you can use "Greater or equal to instead of equal"

Comment: As ᴀ ɴᴏᴛᴇ ғᴏʀ ғᴜᴛᴜʀᴇ ʀᴇғʀᴇɴᴄᴇ, ʏᴏᴜ ᴄᴀɴ ᴄʜᴀɴɢᴇ ᴛʜᴇ ʟᴀʙᴇʟ ғʀᴏᴍ ғɪxᴇᴅ ғᴏɴᴛ sɪᴢᴇ ᴛᴏ ᴀ ᴍɪɴɪᴍᴜᴍ ғᴏɴᴛ sɪᴢᴇ ɪɴᴄᴀsᴇ ʏᴏᴜ ᴡᴀɴᴛ ᴛᴏ ғɪx ᴛʜᴇ sɪᴢᴇ ᴏғ ᴛʜᴇ ʟᴀʙᴇʟ.

Comment: Yes but that's different case

Comment: Jᴜsᴛ sʜᴀʀɪɴɢ ᴇxᴛʀᴀ ɪɴғᴏ. Mᴀʏ ʙᴇ ʜᴇʟᴘғᴜʟ ᴛᴏ ғᴜᴛᴜʀᴇ ᴄᴏᴅᴇʀs.